# NSSM - Install windows service to run daphne server for django channels

Tags: python, windows, service, command-line, nssm

I run the commands on a windows machine as shown below to start my server,

```
D:\django_channels> django_channels_env\Scripts\activate
(django_channels_env) D:\django_channels\djanog_project> daphne -e ssl:8000:privateKey=cert\\development.key:certKey=cert\\development.crt --ws-protocol "graphql-ws" --proxy-headers django_project.asgi:application
```

I'm using nssm, to make this as windows service.

I have pasted, `daphne` command in a text file and saved as `.bat` file.

**nssm config:**

```
path = C:\Python\Python36\python.exe
Startup directory = D:\Django channels\django_channels_env
Arguments = "D:\Django channels\real_time_table\ws_daphne.bat"
```

**ws_daphne.bat:**

```
daphne -e ssl:8000:privateKey=cert\\development.key:certKey=cert\\development.crt --ws-protocol "graphql-ws" --proxy-headers project_name.asgi:application
```

**Error:**

```
  File "D:\Django channels\real_time_table\ws_daphne.bat", line 1
    daphne -e ssl:8000:privateKey=cert\\development.key:certKey=cert\\development.crt --ws-protocol "graphql-ws" --proxy-headers real_time_table.asgi:application
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone please guide me to run `daphne` in a virtual environment as windows service?

Answer (score 0):

We need to run `daphne.exe`, which exists in our virtual environment.

**XXXX.bat file:**

```
call "D:\Django\Django channels\django_channels_env\Scripts\daphne.exe" -e ssl:8000:privateKey=cert\\development.key:certKey=cert\\development.crt --ws-protocol "graphql-ws" --proxy-headers real_time_table.asgi:application
```

**nssm config:**

```
path = your\path\env\to\bat_folder\XXXX.bat
Startup directory = your\path\env\to\bat_folder
Arguments = leave empty
```

By this, `daphne` is now working as a windows service.

Comment: Have you faces any issue with running this configuration at Windows so far?